# Difference in usage of 'explanative' and 'explanatory'

Tags: word-usage

I found myself using 'explanative' recently, then had to double-check that it's actually a word.

The [dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/explanative) lists 'explanative' as an alternative of 'explanatory', but is there a reason to prefer one or the other in specific circumstances?

Comment: To the extent they are both actual words meaning the same thing, *[explanative](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=explanative%2Cexplanatory&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexplanative%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexplanatory%3B%2Cc0)* is almost never used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most everywhere I look suggests that they are interchangable, though explanatory holds a massive preference. [Ngrams suggest](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=explanative%2Cexplanatory&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexplanative%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexplanatory%3B%2Cc0) that the most favorable situation for "explanative" was in 1751 when it was used 1/25th as often as "explanatory." If you worry about using words that make others think twice, use explanatory. If you tend to be less trepid, you may want to use each and appropriately. Therefore, let's examine the meaning of the words by considering their suffixes.

According to Merriam Webster (there is some slight variation amongst references) the suffixes are very similar.

The suffix -ative implies:

- relating to or connected with something
- designed to do something
- tending to do something

Whereas the suffix -atory implies:

- of, belonging to, or connected with
- serving or tending to

The only difference I see is that -ative includes the facet of being designed to do something. So, if we were going to [split hairs](http://buttersafe.com/2018/03/08/precise-slice/), Then this *explanative* sentence could belong to the explanation or be designed to explain the difference. Whereas this *explanatory* sentence cannot be designed to explain the difference and must only tend to explain the difference, though either sentence can belong to or be connected to this explanation.

Consider also the other words which carry each suffix; [Words ending in -atory](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-atory) versus [words ending in -ative.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-ative) IMHO, the difference is that most of the atory words describe something which is happening (E.G. potatory, observatory, salutatory) whereas most of the ative words describe the way a thing is (E.G. authoritative, putative, backative) I must admit, however, that some reverse the trend (E.G. explorative or derogatory)

Comment: hopefully some intrepid grammarian will elucidate the terms for "describe the way a thing is" contra "describe something which is happening." I'm ignorant of such, being more of the linguistic school